# Android StringArray with settext

Tags: android, arrays

I'm developing an app that displays some textviews for the user, and I thought that I would store the text in an array and load the information accordingly to chosen item from a listview

Each StringArray has a name and 4 items. I'm using an if statement to know which array to use and then set the text accordingly.

However I can't get it right it seems.. LogCat gives me FATALEXCEPTION and the program closes right away when I try to access the activity.

Used code

```
if (s.equals("A_DuGamla")) {
    String[] banan_arr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hello);
    songname.setText(banan_arr[0]);
    lyricsby.setText(banan_arr[1]);
    melody.setText(banan_arr[2]);
    lyrics.setText(banan_arr[3]);
} else if (s.equals("A_Kungs")) { 
// And so on..
```

And the StringArray

```
<string-array name="hello">
    <item>Visa</item>
    <item>Text</item>
    <item>Melodi</item>
    <item>Text</item>
</string-array>
```

thanks in advance

UPDATE ERROR LOG

```
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable toinstantiate activity ComponentInfo{se.noxious.visboken/se.noxious.visboken.R1_TradVisor}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1743)
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903):    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:356)
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903):    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:351)
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903):    at se.noxious.visboken.R1_TradVisor.<init>(R1_TradVisor.java:19)
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1040)
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1735)
05-13 21:05:20.771: E/AndroidRuntime(25903):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: there it is, dont say much though for my eyes:/

Comment: It appears you're trying to find a preference by name that doesn't exist, from your `R1_TradVisor` contructor (line 19). So, what does that constructor look like?

Comment: on that line I had some SharedPreferences, a code that I had working earlier, however if I comment everything that has with that line to do i get error on line 36: `songname.setText(banan_arr[0]);` by saying constructor do you mean my onCreate method? @raju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key line in the logcat is

```
at se.noxious.visboken.R1_TradVisor.<init>(R1_TradVisor.java:19)
```

Check line 19 in file R1_TradVisor.java - that's where the error is.  Whatever object you're dealing with on that line is `null` (`NullPointerException`).

Comment: Thank you, my issue was declaring the `setupVars()` method too late in the oncreate method, thats why it wasn't working as it didnt know the reference of it. Also i learned about logcat :) cheers